# Columns are not adjusting while creating dynamic layout?

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout

I am using android studio in which I have created dynamic table layout inside a fragment, but there is some problem  due to which my columns are not setting equal throughout.For test i am using string as json the code  as given below.There will be 4 objects that will be created by this string so layout will be created accordingly with 8 textViews(1 will be blank) and will repeat 4 time but data is showing ony 1.5 timw(wierd)

java file->

```
   String alllist ="[{\"OrderID\":\"1\",\"userID\":\"mananpandya.sgvu@gmail.com\",\"Order_Given\":\"2015-10-13 11:12:25\",\"Services\":[\"Washing\",\"ironing\",\"woollen washing\",\"washing + folding\"],\"Schedule_Pickup\":\"11-10-15 10:00-1:00\",\"Schedule_Delivery\":\"13-10-15 10:00-1:00\",\"No_Of_Clothes\":\"15\",\"Weight_Clothes\":\"5kg\",\"Total_Amount\":\"400\",\"OrderStage\":\"4\"},{\"OrderID\":\"13\",\"userID\":\"mananpandya.sgvu@gmail.com\",\"Order_Given\":\"2015-10-13 11:16:25\",\"Schedule_Pickup\":\"12-10-15 10\",\"Schedule_Delivery\":\"12-15-10 12\",\"No_Of_Clothes\":\"20\",\"Weight_Clothes\":\"10kg\",\"Total_Amount\":\"250\",\"OrderStage\":\"1\"},{\"OrderID\":\"14\",\"userID\":\"mananpandya.sgvu@gmail.com\",\"Order_Given\":\"2015-10-13 11:16:28\",\"Schedule_Pickup\":\"12-10-15 10\",\"Schedule_Delivery\":\"12-15-10 12\",\"No_Of_Clothes\":\"22\",\"Weight_Clothes\":\"7kg\",\"Total_Amount\":\"750\",\"OrderStage\":\"3\"},{\"OrderID\":\"15\",\"userID\":\"mananpandya.sgvu@gmail.com\",\"Order_Given\":\"2015-10-13 11:16:28\",\"Schedule_Pickup\":\"12-10-15 10\",\"Schedule_Delivery\":\"12-15-10 12\",\"No_Of_Clothes\":\"22\",\"Weight_Clothes\":\"7kg\",\"Total_Amount\":\"750\",\"OrderStage\":\"2\"}]";


   try {

        JSONArray j1 = new JSONArray(alllist);
        tl = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.allprevordertable);


        tl.removeAllViews();
        for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++) {
            JSONObject job = j1.getJSONObject(z);
            tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView ordername = new TextView(getActivity());
            ordername.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            ordername.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF52caf7"));

            ordername.setText("Order " + job.getString("OrderID"));

            tr.addView(ordername);

            TextView trackorder = new TextView(getActivity());
            trackorder.setText("track order");
            trackorder.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF52caf7"));
            trackorder.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(trackorder);
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


            tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView pdate = new TextView(getActivity());
            pdate.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            pdate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF52caf7"));

            pdate.setText("pickup: " + job.getString("Order_Given"));

            tr.addView(pdate);

            TextView blank = new TextView(getActivity());
            blank.setText("");
            blank.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF52caf7"));
            blank.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(blank);
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


            tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView stype = new TextView(getActivity());
            stype.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            stype.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF52caf7"));

            stype.setText(job.getString("Services"));

            tr.addView(stype);

            TextView cost = new TextView(getActivity());
            cost.setText("Rs." + job.getString("Total_Amount"));
            cost.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF52caf7"));
            cost.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(cost);
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



            tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView weight = new TextView(getActivity());
            weight.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF52caf7"));

            weight.setText(job.getString("Weight_Clothes"));

            tr.addView(weight);

            TextView status = new TextView(getActivity());
            status.setText(job.getString("OrderStage") );
            status.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF52caf7"));
            status.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(status);
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


 xml layout:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/pbackground">



<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/allprevordertable"

    android:stretchColumns="*">



</TableLayout>
```

Comment: the output is shown  here at : http://postimg.org/image/uzhik856r/

Comment: Also I want to know the correct way to design this type of TableLayout : http://postimg.org/image/bccwevp13/

Comment: I though people are interested in android???? yet no one has give me the solution.